# How to Warp vector file based on control points in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector

I have a very comprehensive polyline file that, when compared with imagery, is obviously offset by a few hundred meters, but the offset varies from one area to another. It would be easy for me to create a set of control points to correct this, but I can't find the correct tool to do so. I'm using ArcMap, and have just about every ESRI extension known to man, if that helps.

I've entertained the idea of creating a raster and using the raster warp tool, then reconverting back to vector, but I don't want the inevitable loss of fidelity from multiple conversions. If anyone has another way to do this I'm all ears.

Comment: The topic that I think you are looking for is spatial adjustment which will enable you to rubber sheet your vectors.

Comment: I'll look into it. The terms I've been searching are warp and transform.

Comment: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000000t5000000.htm

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need. I feel pretty dumb - I was searching through toolboxes for an hour and a half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the topic that you are looking for is **[Spatial Adjustment](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/About_spatial_adjustment/01m800000030000000/)**, and in particular **[Rubber Sheeting](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/About_spatial_adjustment_rubbersheeting/01m80000000z000000/)**:

> In rubbersheeting adjustments, you are usually trying to align one
>   layer with another that is often in close proximity. The source layer
>   (drawn with solid lines) is adjusted to the more accurate target
>   layer. During rubbersheeting, the surface is literally stretched,
>   moving features using a piecewise transformation that preserves
>   straight lines. During this process, you place links to stretch or
>   warp the data you are trying to align to the underlying datasets.